# How to find whether element is disabled in Selenium when disabled is given inside class attribute

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Suppose I have a html element
 and 
 abc

How to find that element is disabled in Selenium. Since there is no such attribute disabled, how to find that in webdriver that a tag is disabled

Comment: <a class= "abc"> and <a class= "abc disabled">. This is the example html tags

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you can check the property "Enabled" e.g. `var isEnable = element.Enabled;`

In case your application change style to present state disabled, you can check it by `var isEnable = element.GetAttribute('class').Contains("disabled");`

Comment: Its not working. because enabled is working only when we have a attribute disabled. Here disabled attribute is not available and disable is given inside class.

Comment: @Kriez Your welcome. Could you accept my answer so we can close the question?